# How do I set the origin of an Armature

Tags: origin

Using Blender 2.8, I'm trying to move the origin of the armature.

I have uploaded my blend file [here](http://pasteall.org/blend/index.php?id=52980).

I am able to move the origin of the mesh, but not the origin of the armature.

I have uploaded a [video here](https://youtu.be/Zd6kMZTr6Kw) that shows how I'm trying it.

When I export my armature-mesh-object to Unity, the origin is the origin of the armature, that is what I need to change the origin of the armature. Changing only the origin of the mesh wouldn't help.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In object mode, put the 3D cursor where you want the origin to be, then select the armature and choose "set origin - origin to 3D cursor".

If you need precision for the placing, select the place (maybe a vertex, a face, a bone or whatever) and press Shift S "Cursor to selected", then again set origin.

[image]

When inspecting your file, turn off this option (that I don't even knew it existed).

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Can you tell me why it's not possible to move the origin like I move the origin for a mesh?

Comment: When you're using the grab tool you're moving yhe whole object, not only its origin, but the vertex stay in place because they're hold by the bones action. When you do the same for the armature, the bones carry the vertices with them. So, also for mesh this is the correct way to set the origin.

Comment: Expecially for exporting, it's a good habit to model starting from the world center and finishing with both mesh and armature with origin in world center (loc 0,0,0). In this case you can press Ctrl A Apply loc, rot and scale, so that mesh and rig have default transform values ( 0,0,0 - 0,0,0 - 1,1,1).

Comment: Could you perhaps upload your version to pasteall.org? I would really like to see how you would do it / where you would place everything. That would be really nice.

Comment: Or a video? I just don't understand what the Armature does and why it has its own origin. :-( :-(

Comment: http://pasteall.org/blend/index.php?id=52991 I also updated my answer.

Comment: Dank u wel!!!!!